# Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Tags: php, sockets, email

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("tls://smtp.gmail.com", 465, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
   echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
          } else {
   echo "opened";
         } 
?>
```

While I am running this file  getting the error in browser :
unable to connect to tls://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\AppServ\www\test1\tls.php on line 3
ERROR: 71756200 - Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Open your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`) and see if the `openssl` extension is enabled there or not.

The statement generally appears as follows:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Confirm the same with the output of `phpinfo()`.